# closing userform by checking sheetname in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

By using a commandbotton can a userform be closed by checking if a particular sheet name is present in the workbook

```
Private Sub Close1_Click()
' Protect and Hide

 Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "FSS-TEM-00025") Then
            (ws.Name, "FSS-TEM-00025" ).Select
            ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
            Unload Me
        Else
            Unload Me
        End If
    Next

    'Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.  You're not using the ws reference properly after the If...

```
Private Sub Close1_Click()
' Protect and Hide

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If InStr(1, ws.Name, "FSS-TEM-00025") Then
        ws.Select 'this line is different
        ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False 'hides the activesheet
        Unload Me
    End If
Next

'Unload Me
End Sub
```

And instead of selecting then using the activesheet:

```
ws.Select 'this line is different            
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

Can just be

```
ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob!!! It really works now, but Ineed to avoid one thing in this. When I run this the sheet in which the button for the form gets hidden . Can you tell me how can I fix that too.

Comment: If you don't want the sheet hidden, comment out the line that sets `.Visible = False`.  I also took out the `Else` statement since the form was being unloaded even if it didn't find the sheet.